# How to stop try and catch from infinitely looping

Tags: java, loops, methods

Trying to create a loop that will repeat if anything other than 1 2 3 4 5 is entered or if an input mismatch occurs. Im very new to try and catch and my teacher says I need to frequently use them for this assignment. Im not sure as to why this keeps infinitely looping. Ive been playing around with this for hours, and every different solution i think i have, ends in a recurring loop that prints forever. Thanks to anyone who can help.

```
do {
    System.out.printf("Please enter the number corresponding with with what would like to edit: %n1. Title%n2. Author%n3. Location%n4. Book Type%n5. Book Status%n");
    try {
        x = scan.nextInt();
        if (x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3 && x != 4 && x != 5) {
            System.out.println("you must enter either 1 2 3 4 5");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("you must enter either 1 2 3 4 5");
        x = 0;
    }
} while (x != 1 && x != 2 && x != 3 && x != 4 && x != 5);
```

Comment: Add `scan.nextLine()` to your **`catch`**. Current behavior: give me the next int, there isn't one so throw an exception, give me the next int ... it's still not an int...

Comment: @SukhpalSingh `x != 1 || x != 2` will be true for all values of `x`. `&&` seems correct here.

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `scan.nextLine` here:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("you must enter either 1 2 3 4 5");
    x = 0;
    scan.nextLine(); <----
}
```

This is because if the scanner reads something that is not an integer, it will not consume the input, as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Scanner.html):

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. **If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.**

So the next time you call `nextInt`, the scanner still tries to read the invalid int, which it fails to do, creating an infinite loop.

Adding a `nextLine` makes sure that the invalid int is consumed.